# How to Pass Key Value Parameter in JSON POST method in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, post

This is API http://itaag-env-1.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/filter/taggedusers/

**its parameter**:  "contactsList" : ["5987606147", "6179987671", "5082508888"]

**its header**: ["deviceid": "584D97F-761A-4C24-8C4B-C145A8B8BD75", "userType": "personal", "key": "9609cc826b0d472faf9967370c095c21"]

In my code if i put breakpoint then `filtertaggedUser()` is calling but i am unable to go inside **completionHandler**  the access is not going inside `dataTask`

Access going to else part why? the api is working.

i am trying to pass parameter key value in URL string like below

```
 let urlStr  = "http://itaag-env-1.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/filter/taggedusers/?contactsList=" + "8908908900"
```

is this correct approch?

code for above API:

```
 func filtertaggedUser() {
    print("inside filter taggedusers")

    let headers = ["deviceid": "584D97F-761A-4C24-8C4B-C145A8B8BD75", "userType": "personal", "key": "9609cc826b0d472faf9967370c095c21"]
    let urlStr  = "http://itaag-env-1.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/filter/taggedusers/?contactsList=" + "8908908900"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:urlStr)! as URL,cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod          = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            // access not coming here
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            if httpResponse!.statusCode == 200 {
                print("filter taggedusers inside")

                do {
                    print("filter taggedusers inside do")

                    let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String :AnyObject]
                    print("filter taggedusers \(jsonObject)")


                } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
            } else { Constants.showAlertView(alertViewTitle: "", Message: "Something went wrong, Please try again", on: self) }

    })
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

OUTPUT:

[POSTMAN OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUQb5.png)

[POSTMAN Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q98a.png)

why response is not coming, where i did mistake, please help me with the code.

Comment: Do you see any of the print outputs?

Comment: Is the API returning 200 statusCode in postman? I am getting 400 Bad request .

Comment: @VinayakaSY, you need to give header and parameter..... pls give` "deviceid": "584D97F-761A-4C24-8C4B-C145A8B8BD75", "userType": "personal", "key": "9609cc826b0d472faf9967370c095c21"`

Comment: @VinayakaSY, i have edited post.. pls have a look... and pls help me with code

Comment: @koen, only first print statement is coming.. and it goes to else statement

Comment: @VinayakaSY, pls use above mentioned API.. i have changed API

Comment: can you provide the details added in the body ? (Json string)

Comment: @VinayakaSY,  in Body parameter: `"contactsList": ["8908908900"]` ... added it post with screen shot

Comment: @VinayakaSY  helllooo did u got response in code

Comment: Yes got it, checking the code.

Comment: @VinayakaSY if u got response in code, pls post answer

Comment: yeah, i have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can call the `Post` request API like below,

```
func getPostString(params:[String:Any]) -> String
    {
        var data = [String]()
        for(key, value) in params
        {
            data.append(key + "=\(value)")
        }
        print(data.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "&"))
        return data.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "&")
    }

    func callPostApi(){
        let url = URL(string: "http://itaag-env-1.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/filter/taggedusers/")
        guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("584D97F-761A-4C24-8C4B-C145A8B8BD75", forHTTPHeaderField: "deviceid")
        request.setValue("9609cc826b0d472faf9967370c095c21", forHTTPHeaderField: "key")
        request.setValue("personal", forHTTPHeaderField: "userType")


        let parameters = getPostString(params:   ["contactsList":["8908908900"]])
        request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
        // Perform HTTP Request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse!.statusCode)
                // Check for Error
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error took place \(error)")
                    return
                }

                // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
                if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
                }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Output :

```
{"8908908900":{"userId":"9609cc826b0d472faf9967370c095c21","userName":"Satish Madhavarapu","profilePic":null,"oniTaag":true,"tagged":false,"userType":"personal"}}
```

Comment: you mean device id?

Comment: no `tagged ` value and `userId ` value from response data

Comment: you left it in middle.. how to get `tagged ` and `userName ` values from response

Comment: do you know how to get `userName` from response.. pls post the code

Comment: sorry, i was not around. Hope you got the solution for  json parsing.